# create 1D array from data frame column

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am looking for a way to get class label from my dataframe containing rows of features.

For instance, in this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['1',   'a',    'bb',   '0'],
['1',   'a',    'cc',   '0'],
['2', 'a',    'dd',   '1'],
['2',   'a',    'ee',   '1'],
['3', 'a',    'ff',   '2'],
['3', 'a',    'gg',   '2'],
['3', 'a',    'hh',   '2']], columns = ['ID', 'name', 'type', 'class'])

df 
    ID  name    type class
0   1    a      bb      0
1   1    a      cc      0
2   2    a      dd      1
3   2    a      ee      1
4   3    a      ff      2
5   3    a      gg      2
6   3    a      hh      2
```

My class array should be (i.e. for each `ID` the  `class` value should be picked once):

```
class
array([0., 1., 2.,])
```

**EDIT**

`df['class'].values`
produces `array(['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'], dtype=object)`

Expected answer:

I want `array([0, 1, 2])`

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('ID')['class']`

Comment: As created the dataframe contains strings in the column.  That's what `values` is giving you.

Comment: @wwii exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case multiple IDs can have same class, you can select your 'ID' and 'class' columns and drop duplicates, then fetch class column. Otherwise, simply use unique as suggested in other answer (of course you can convert this answer to ints too):

```
df[['ID','class']].drop_duplicates()['class'].values
#['0' '1' '2']
```

or similar to @wii's suggestion in comments:

```
df.drop_duplicates('ID')['class'].values
#['0' '1' '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby`+ `unique()` as the following:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['class'].unique().astype(int).to_numpy()
array([0, 1, 2])
```

For **given** `dataframe`, you can use the following methods:

**Solution 1 : [`Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html):**

```
>>> df['class'].unique()
array(['0', '1', '2'], dtype=object)

#in case you want int outputs
>>> df['class'].unique().astype(int)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

**Solution 2  [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)**:

```
>>> df['class'].value_counts(ascending=True).index.to_numpy().astype(int)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: The issue with this answer is if you have other `íd` having a class that was previously listed, the value won't be included (say `id =10` follows with class `0`, this will not appear in the intended array since the class already exists.